# Why does a loop through a list of lists not recognise, that a list is a copy

Tags: python, python-2.7, list

I encountered a (in my opinion) extremely strange behavior, when looping through a list of lists. It is very difficult to explain, but here is an example code:

```
k = [[0],[1],[2]]

for lis in k:
    lis_copy = lis
    lis_copy.append(0)
    print lis
```

When executing this, I get:

```
[0, 0]
[1, 0]
[2, 0]
```

This is very strange for me, as the list which is appended is a copy of lis,
but lis is appended as well. I would assume this list to be untouched.
For example doing the same with a list of integers the following happens:

```
k = [0,1,2]

for num in k:
    num_copy = num
    num_copy = 0
    print num
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
```

Just as expected num is not touched by the manipulation of num_copy.

If somebody could explain why this is happening and how to avoid this, 
like how to disconnect the lis_copy from is, that would be great.

Wow, I am amazed I did not encounter mayor problems before, without knowing this. I think I should review quiet some of my code. Anyway I thought this is somehow connected to the loop, this seems not to be the case, therefore I think the best explanation can be found here:

[How to clone or copy a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html

Comment: I think you're missing some key knowledge about Python here - read this for an overview of calling be reference and calling by name:
http://www.python-course.eu/passing_arguments.php

Comment: lis_copy = lis does not create a new list, it simply points to the original list. Python3 has a copy method but I think you have to slice the list to copy in 2.7. Something like lis_copy = list[:]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `copy.copy()` or `copy.deepcopy()`to avoid this behavior:

```
import copy

k = [[0],[1],[2]]

for lis in k:
    lis_copy = copy.copy(lis)
    lis_copy.append(0)
    print lis
```

Output:

```
[0]
[1]
[2]
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html

Answer (score 2):

This is because Python lists (and dicts) are not copied to a new list, but the new list becomes a reference to that list. if you truly want to copy the list, use deepcopy

Comment: can you give an example, why a copy of the list with reference is needed, I just wondered where the advantage of that behavior is ?

Answer (score 1):

Case a:

```
k = [[0],[1],[2]]

for lis in k:
    lis_copy = lis
    lis_copy.append(0)
    print lis
```

We have a pointer to a list, and inside the loop we have another pointer made that points to the inner list objects. Then a zero is appended to each object.

Case b:

```
k = [0,1,2]

for num in k:
    num_copy = num
    num_copy = 0
    print num
```

We have a pointer to a list, and inside the loop we have another pointer made that points to the inner integers. The difference is that in this case the pointer is changed to then point to a zero object rather than the list elements.